# Install python 3 and Pyqt5 libraries in centos7 without root rights

Tags: centos, rhel, python, gui, python3

The ultimate aim is to create a GUI using QT designer running on a Centos 7 platform (I am running a centos 7 virtual box on windows 10). I am a beginner in using Linux and following are my questions:

1. How can i install Python3  without using root commands such as sudo, yum , apt-get, pip etc. ? I cant use pip install as there is no internet connection at client side.
2. I also want to install QT5 libraries in the proejct folder without root rights.
3. As far as I read on some forums one way was to download a {python3.}.tgz file on windows and then copy it to Linux/Centos using pip install (not sure how it is done)

Comment: Python3 is available from Centos 7, you don’t need to install it in a separate place.

Comment: Also, Qt 4 is the base qt in RHEL7/CentOS7, do you absolutely need to use a toolkit not supported on that platform?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, you can compile it from sources and install it in e.g. /tmp/python3 or your home directory /home/username/python3.
2. Likewise
3. This most likely won't work.

I'm not sure why you wanna go through all the troubles instead of just taking any popular distro like Fedora or Ubuntu which contain all the required packages already built and ready to use especially since you have full access to your VM.

Comment: we picked centos ecause the customer uses rhel7 . Can you clarify the first answer a bit maybe with few screendumps ?

Comment: https://google.com/search?q=how+to+compile+software+in+linux

Comment: Thanks !! I was able to make test it, however during installation it showed error as zlib missing

Comment: You might need to install `zlib-devel`. Compilation from sources is a special skill.

Comment: I am using the following file to install QT5 librares : " qt-everywhere-src-5.14.0.tar.xz " can be found in QT downloads/archive. However I am now stuck with installation. cd <path>/<source_package>
     ./configure -prefix $PWD/qtbase <license> -nomake tests
     make -j 4  .  What should be the correct way to install ?